# How to paste copied value into InputBox using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I paste the value copied from an Excel cell into an InputBox?

I can paste the same value when copied from Notepad into InputBox.

```vb
Sub input_box()

    Dim Input_value as variant

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Input_value = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter ID", Title:="Enter ID")
    If Input_value = "" Or Input_value = Empty Then
        msg = MsgBox("Please enter ID!", vbCritical + vbDefaultButton1, "Error")
        goto ends:
    end if
ends:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End sub
```

Comment: If I copy a cell, and then run your code I _am_ able to paste into the input box, but, with un-declared variables, it's apparent that what you have posted isn't _all_ of your code, e.g. a line such as `Application.CutCopyMode = False` earlier in your code would definitely prevent pasting.

Comment: Thanks. but i haven't used Application.CutCopyMode = False. Is there any solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue i faced is resolved by disabling Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual.
Now the pasting of values, copied from excel cell is working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Is Input_Value declared as a variant, string, integer, ...?
Also, the full syntax for InputBox includes a type (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox)

The type should match how you're declared Input_Value. It will also help edit out bad input

Comment: Thanks. I declared Input_Value as variant and made the changes like you said. Still cannot able to fix the issue